# Bind DBContext Entity to Model on .Net Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core, dbcontext, webapi

I have a model class which looks like below:

```
public class ProductsViewModel
{
        public int ProductId { get; set; }
        public string ProductName { get; set; }
        public bool IsActive{ get; set; }
}
```

And bellow the Entity:

```
    [Table("Products")]
    public partial class Products
    {    
        [Column("ProductId")]
        public int ProductId { get; set; }
        [Column("ProductName")]
        public string ProductName{ get; set; }
        [Column("IsActive")]
        public bool IsActive { get; set; }
    }
```

I'm fetching the result using the below LINQ query, which is returning correct data:

```
List<Products> productData = _context.Products
    .Where(x => x.IsActive == true).ToList();
```

Now, I want to bind this data *i.e* `productData` with my model, something similar to `ProductsViewModel = productData`.

I know I can loop through `productData` records and assign values to model properties but I am looking for a direct way to map these two.

Is there any quick wat to get all the `productData` assigned to my model?

Comment: Use Linq `Select` method. It sounds like you have run through a basic Entity Framework tutorial and then stopped before getting to that stuff. I suggest you go back to it or find a better one :)

Comment: Also that's an entity not a db context. Db Context is all of the entities as DbSets and the connection to the DB (plus some other stuff). Specifically it implements DbContext.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *Is there any quick wat to get all the `productData` assigned to my model?*

There are several. You can use *Automapper* as stated in another answer, alternatively, also using *Automapper*, and for more complex mapping, you can configure [AutoMapper profiles](https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Configuration.html#profile-instances) for whatever exotic mappings you need.

For a direct assignment using `=`, like you exemplify in your question, and I reckon can be the simpler way for less complex entities, you can do it by overloading the assignment operator in the `ProductsViewModel` class:

```
public class ProductsViewModel
{
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }

    public static implicit operator ProductsViewModel(Products obj)
    {
        return new ProductsViewModel()
        {
            ProductName = obj.ProductName,
            IsActive = obj.IsActive,
            ProductId = obj.ProductId,
        };
    }
}
```

Now your direct assignment will work fine.

For you example, using `Select` and cast which is also possible due to the operator overloading:

```
var productsViewModels = _context.Products.Where(x => x.IsActive)
    .Select(x => (ProductsViewModel)x).ToList();
```

Or explicit direct assignment:

```
var productsViewModels = _context.Products.Where(p => p.IsActive)
    .Select(x => { ProductsViewModel model = x; return model; }).ToList();
```

Here you have [some running code](https://onlinegdb.com/C7sYY9YJS) you can consult for your convenience.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a mapping framework, the one I use the most is Automapper https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Getting-started.html.

```
 public class AClass {
      private readonly IMapper _mapper;
      private readonly ADbContext _dbContext;

      public AClass (IMapper mapper, ADBContext dbContext)
      {
          _mapper = mapper;
          _dbContext = dbContext;
      }

      public async Task<IEnumerable<ProductViewModel>> AMethod()
      {
           var dbProducts = await _dbContext.Products.Where(x => x.IsActive == true).ToListAsync();
           return dbProducts.Select(x => _mapper.Map<ProductViewModel>(x))
      }
 }
```